# use Placeholder in Tomcats Server.xml

Tags: tomcat, ant

i have a little problem and see no solution for it.
I need flexible ports for my tomcat. I want to set a port variable in a properties file and tomcat read this and start the server on this port. I know that tomcat can't read from properties but he can read system variables/properties.
I build my project and tomcat with ant, this means the solution lies in ant.

**server.xml**

```
<Connector
    port="${tomcat.http.port}" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" ...
</Connector>
```

**build.xml**

```
<exec dir="${basedir}/tomcat/bin" executable="${basedir}/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh" failonerror="true" output="${basedir}/tomcat/logs/testrun.log">
    <arg value="start" />
</exec>
```

**project.properties**

```
tomcat.http.port=42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do, I have a server.xml tomcat file with placeholder properties in:

```
<Connector port="@http.port@" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="@https.port@" />
```

Then in my ant build.xml:

```
<copy todir="${dir.destination.config.tomcat}" filtering="true">
        <fileset dir="${dir.with.template.config.tomcat}"/>

        <filterset>
            <filter token="http.port" value="${http.port}"/>
            <filter token="https.port" value="${https.port}"/>
            <filter token="admin.port" value="${admin.port}"/>
            <filter token="control.port" value="${control.port}"/>
        </filterset>
    </copy>
```

And run your ant build with -Dhttp.port=42 or put that in a properties file loaded by ant.

Comment: What can be <fileset dir="${dir.with.template.config.tomcat}"/> concrete? Is this my server.xml?

Comment: Cool i think it works. Thank you for your help. The template.config can be the server.xml.